# How to change php-cli to match phpinfo (7.3 => 7.4) Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, apache2, php, php-cli

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and I want to make my `php -v` match my `phpinfo` page.

`php -v` from the command line:

```
PHP 7.3.13 (cli) (built: Jan  8 2020 14:07:34) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.13, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

`phpinfo` page:

```
PHP Version 7.4.1
```

I tried doing

```
sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

Which allowed my `phpinfo` to change to php 7.4 but this does not change my cli `php -v` output.

I also tried to use:

```
set PATH="/usr/bin/php7.4/bin:$PATH"
```

But this still doesn't change it.

I am out of ideas. Any help?

Comment: How did you install PHP 7.4 and 7.3? What does the command `type php` return? `set PATH` is the Windows syntax for setting an environment variable, use `export` in Linux.